# Backbone routing for modular and multiple views

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-routing

So I'm in a bit of dilema with my Backbone routing design and am trying to see what other folks think or have attempted to do to solve this problem.

The basic problem is that I'm writing an application with multiple views, and nested views within each of the views, and trying to avoid using one backbone router to control the state of these views and nested views.

Example of the problem is:

```
Backbone.Router.extend({ routes: 
'view1' : ..., 'view2Nested': ..., 
'View2NestedNested' ...});
```

View layout:

- View1

  - View1Nested
- View2

  - View2Nested
  - View2NestedNested

In this configuration, the router has to now about View2NestedNested in order to send it any action information possibly meaning that the main router has to hold a reference to the view or know about view2 and get it's reference to view2Nested, and ask that view for view2NestedNested.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is creating the view with a reference to it's parent.

So basically your views will look like this :

```
var ViewAA = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
         this.parent = options.parent
    },

    render: function() {
         this.parent.router.navigate("viewA/viewAA");
    }
});

var ViewA = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
         this.router = options.router
    },

    render: function() {
       this.nestedView = new ViewAA({ parent: this });
    }
});

var router = new Router();

var viewA = new ViewA({ router: router });
```

Second approach, that I'm using in more complex applications is using ONE global variable... It looks something like this :

```
var ViewAA = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {

    },

    render: function() {
         app.router.navigate("viewA/viewAA");
    }
});

app = {
    router: new Router(),
    classes: {
        ViewA: Backbone.View.extend({ ... }),
        ViewAA: Backbone.View.extend({ ... })
    },
}

app.viewA = new app.classes.ViewA();
app.viewAA = new app.classes.ViewAA();
```

Hint: Using RequireJS and AMD approach is always better, so you might want to try that too.

Comment: I am using requirejs, still need to do all of the reference management

Comment: Why? just use `module.exports = new Router()` in your `router.js` file and then `this.router = require('router');` in your views

Comment: So you're idea is to have one large router, that's fine, but you still are leaning towards tons of indirection to get to the nested views, view1.view2nested.view2nestednested ....

Comment: Using a global variable for your views and routers is the best way of managing references in big web apps. If you use multiple routers it is never a problem to place them there too... One example is https://github.com/documentcloud/documentcloud/blob/master/public/javascripts/application.js by the creator of Backbone.